# log file is not created using log4net

Tags: log4net, app-config, log4net-configuration

I have downloaded the log4net.dll and added that as a service reference.
One of the project I have created has app.config where I have made the following configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>       
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\<myid>\\Desktop\\error.log"/>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have an Entry form and created and declared

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
  (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

this inside the partial class and the the logging I have used here

```
 private void Entry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        logger.Debug("logged");            
    }
```

and I have added

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config", Watch = true)]
```

in Assemblyinfo.cs class

and also added this in the main.cs class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            logger.Debug("app started");
    }
```

The log file itself is not created and when I debug it runs through these codes properly.
I am using log4net.dll version 1.2.13 for desktop applications using .net 4.0 c#.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@peer is right, you need to pick one method of configuring log4net and use it correctly.

I think your immediate problem though is you've specified `app.config` as the config file in your assembly attribute, but you must specify `your_app_name.exe.config` as that will be the file's name after the project is built (the name will differ depending on the actual name of your app, look in the build output directory to see what it is called)

Alternatively, as "[If neither of the ConfigFile or ConfigFileExtension properties are specified, the application configuration file (e.g. TestApp.exe.config) will be used as the log4net configuration file.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes)" just omit the ConfigFile attribute altogether:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

(The documentation states that is **is** possible to watch an app.config file, as long as you pass the FileInfo to `ConfigureAndWatch` or use an assembly attribute.)

If you have any more problems, though, set log4net into debug mode with the declaration `<log4net debug=true>` in the config and check the Trace output at runtime for any reported configuration issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized log4net 3 different ways, first make a choose how to initialize and configure log4net. The only way to configure an application using the System.Configuration APIs is to call the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(). So you have to remove the assembly: log4net attribute. If you want to use a log4net configfile, you can best do this by the attribute in the assembly.cs. The last way enables you to change the configuration while your application is running.

[Please read the manual on configuring log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: You **can** use an `app.config` file when using assembly attributes to configure log4net - from your link: "If neither of the ConfigFile or ConfigFileExtension properties are specified, the application configuration file (e.g. TestApp.exe.config) will be used as the log4net configuration file."

Comment: @stuartd - I have now created a new log4net.config file to manage the settings. Should I also add the .xml file that I have when I downloaded the log4net.dll?

Comment: @ stuartd - Yes it was able to configure the same after reading the manual now I am able to create and log.